# Random selection from Rails database works on Index, not on its 'Generator page'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, random

I'm writing what's currently a very basic program (and I'm sure very badly-coded, though kinda working) to generate fitness plans, currently split by bodypart or through a generator that selects an item from each bodypart.

I'm having problems with the workout generator though - it works on the index page for testing purposes, with a new workout every time it's refreshed, though on the '/exercises/generator' page where it should live, it will load the index's random workout but not a new plan when refreshed. Looking for a solution to get it working as a standalone generator on this page.

I'm new to this, and have worked to get the program running with what I'm sure is very messy scope and code I'd love to get dryer, so bonus points for tips on correcting this!

If any of the above is unclear, let me know - here's the relevant code from the controller, index.html.erb and bodypart.html.erb (where the generator will sit), along with a partial sitting on the view pages. If there's anything else that would help - shout me.

Controller (less the standard CRUD info)

```
class ExercisesController < ApplicationController

private

def exercise_params
  params.require(:exercise).permit(:move, :bodypart) 
end

public  

  attr_accessor :move, :bodypart

def index

@exercise = Exercise.new
@exercises = Exercise.all

$gen = Exercise.pluck(:move, :bodypart)
$gen.shuffle!

    $generatorl = $gen.select { |a, b| b == "legs" } #feel b.downcase should work to grab capitalized :bodyparts, though not working for now
    $generatorl = $generatorl.first

    $generatorb = $gen.select { |a, b| b == "back" }
    $generatorb = $generatorb.first

    $generators = $gen.select { |a, b| b == "stomach" }
    $generators = $generators.first

    $generatorsh = $gen.select { |a, b| b == "shoulders" }
    $generatorsh = $generatorsh.first

    $generatorc = $gen.select { |a, b| b == "chest" }
    $generatorc = $generatorc.first

$generator = $generatorl, $generatorb, $generators, $generatorsh, $generatorc
$generator.shuffle!

  end   

def bodypart
    @fullpath = request.fullpath

bp = if @fullpath == '/exercises/legs' 
            'legs'
        elsif @fullpath == '/exercises/full'
            'full'
        elsif @fullpath =='/exercises/shoulders'
            'shoulders' 
        elsif @fullpath == '/exercises/back'
            'back'
        elsif @fullpath == '/exercises/chest'
            'chest'
        elsif @fullpath == '/exercises/stomach'
            'stomach'
        elsif @fullpath == '/exercises/generator'
            'generator'
        else
            'error'
        end

    @exercises = if bp == 'error'
                    redirect_to exercises_path
                else
                    Exercise.where(:bodypart => bp)
            end
end
```

(Definitely got the right amount of 'ends' in the real code, in case I've misquoted here)

And the views:

Index

```
<h1>Exercises</h1>

<p></p>

<%= render 'table' %>

<h2> Workout Generator </h2>

 <p> <%= $gen.inspect %> </p>
 <p> <%= $generator.inspect %> </p>
 <p> <%= $generatorl.inspect %> </p>

 <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th><%= "Exercise" %></th>
    <th><%= "Body part" %></th>
  </tr>
  <% $generator.each do |mv, bp|  %>
    <tr>
      <td> <%= mv.titleize %> </td> 
      <td><i> <%= bp.titleize %> </i></td> 
     </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

The view for each bodypart / the generator:

```
<h1>
<% if @fullpath == '/exercises/generator' %>
    <%= 'Generator' %>
<% else %>
    <%= :bodypart.to_s.titleize %></h1>
<% end %>

<h2> Test <%= $fullpath.inspect %> <%= request.fullpath %> </h2>

<% if @exercises.empty? %>
    <p> <%= $gen %> </p>
    <p> <%= $generator %> </p>

     <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th><%= "Exercise" %></th>
    <th><%= "Body part" %></th>
  </tr>
  <% $generator.each do |mv, bp|  %>
    <tr>
      <td> <%= mv.titleize %> </td> 
      <td><i> <%= bp.titleize %> </i></td> 
     </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>

<% else %>

<%= render 'table' %>

<table>
    <tr>
      <td> <%= @exercises.inspect %> </td> 
    </tr>

</table>

<% end %>
```

And finally the partial for Table:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th><%= "Exercise" %></th>
    <th><%= "Body part" %></th>
  </tr>
  <% for exercise in @exercises  %>
    <tr id="exercise_<%= exercise.id %>">
      <td> <%= exercise.move.titleize %> </td> 
      <td><i> <%= exercise.bodypart.titleize %> </i></td> 
      <td> <%= link_to "Edit", edit_exercise_path(exercise) %> </td>
      <td> <%= button_to 'Delete', exercise, :method => :delete %> </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Thanks so much in advance - if I'm being unclear or any other code would be useful, let me know!

Comment: You should probably go through some basic Rails tutorials first. Michael Hartl's rails tutorial is very popular, I can also recommend the classic "Agile Web Development with Rails" and the Rails guides starting here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: This question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, not stackoverflow.